# DC js with large dataset and many dimensions

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

i have been using DC js for profiling with Datatable plugins from year.

Now the requirement is coming up with huge data(>2,00,000 rows) and large number of dimensions (20-30), it's hanging the browser and takes lot of time and filtering also taking long time.

Any Suggestions on improving response time.

i'm already using gzip compression and my json variables length is small.

Any architecture level suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you are talking about 2,000,000+ rows with several dimensions in the browser, you need to start thinking about the limits of the platform. Specifically, since browsers don't use compressed data structures for Javascript objects, the basic question is: "Will the data object fit in the browser memory?" Chrome, at least when I checked a year or so ago, was sitting around a 1GB memory limit. With 2 million rows and 20 dimensions, you will be pushing that just to load the data to the browser.

Given this, I think you need to be thinking architecturally about how you limit the amount of data in the browser while still maintaining interactivity. Start asking question like: "How many dimensions of what cardinality will I actually be displaying at any given time?"

The goal is to decide whether the actual functionality of the application is something the browser can support. If you decide that the browser can support the functionality (it probably can, but it's not a given), then start thinking about how a coordinated browser/server system can provide the type of interactivity that you want.

One way to do this is to dynamically re-aggregate based on what dimensions the user has displayed at any given time. I put together http://lcadata.info a couple of weeks ago as a hacked together example of one approach (it's open source) that uses dc.js on the front end. But there are other ways, and the exact approach may be somewhat unique to the application.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Ethan..., i have reduced JavaScript object by giving short variable names like c1, c2 and separated master data with transaction